# How to set automatically 'many' flag of django serializer depending on input being a list or a single item

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following **machine** model.

```
class Machine(models.Model):
   operators = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='machines', blank=True)
   elasticsearch_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=None, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
   machine_brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
   machine_model = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
   machine_picture = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True)
   tools = models.ManyToManyField('Tool', default=None, blank=True)
   clustered_tags = JSONField(null=True)
   elasticsearch_tags = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=DEFAULT_TAG_MAP)
   machine_slug = models.SlugField()
```

With the following **serializer**.

```
class MachineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
      model = Machine
      fields = '__all__'
```

In my views, I am filtering the data on the company the logged in users belongs to. Now, I want to serialize the object and return it to the client. However, I don't know beforehand whether the queryset is a list of objects or a single object so that I can set the **many** flag of the serializer to **true** or **false**.

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def manage_operators(request):

    user_machines = Machine.objects.filter(company=request.user.company)
    user_machines_ser = MachineSerializer(user_machines, many=True)

    return Response({'machines': user_machines_ser.data})
```

Is there any elegant way to solve this? I could solve it this way but there must be a better way of doing it.

```
if len(user_machines) > 0 :
  user_machine_ser = MachineSerializer(user_machines, many=True)
else:
  user_machine_ser = MachineSerializer(user_machines, many=False)
```

Any input much appreciated!

Comment: since you are running using filter not get, first etc, then  user_machines must be QuerySet right?

Comment: it is a queryset, but it might be a list of querysets or a single one

Comment: @Inigo Do you want to set `many=false` if the queryset contains only a single item?

Comment: @Inigo i  think you are getting confused between a QuerySet and an object

Comment: As @sky wrote `filter` will always return a `QuerySet`. A `QuerySet` may contain none, one or many objects. Allowing `many=True` for a `QuerySet` containing only one objects does no harm. Is there any particular reason for your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are fetching a QuerySet every time, you don't have to set `many=False` if there is only one item in the QuerySet.
So you can safely use

`user_machine_ser = MachineSerializer(user_machines, many=True)`

everytime, no matter how many objects are in the QuerySet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing a **`QuerySet`**, you can use the [**`count()`** [Django doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) method in the **`__init__()`** method of **`MachineSerializer`** by overriding it.

```
class MachineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Machine
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs['instance'].count() > 1: # count() method used here <<<<<
            kwargs['many'] = True
        else:
            kwargs['many'] = False
```